# How to create query for chat app groups with only one address as a parameter?

Tags: mysql, database, join, group-by, chat

Good day everyone, I am currently struggling with writing mysql query which should make chat group from messages. App which I am making is taking data from other service, so it's not up to me to also manage chat groups, I need take this info from messages themselves.

My table of messages looks like this:

| id | sendAddr | receiveAddr | lastMessage | text | read |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Ccbbd6uUZF2GD5wE5LEfjGPA3YWPjoLC6P | CMKovgETx2oYxhoYKAeSakmipBjbmQ9ZHF | 2021-06-02 12:57:39 | test3 | 0 |
| 5 | Ccbbd6uUZF2GD5wE5LEfjGPA3YWPjoLC6P | CMKovgETx2oYxhoYKAeSakmipBjbmQ9ZHF | 2021-06-02 13:00:44 | test3 | 0 |
| 7 | CMKovgETx2oYxhoYKAeSakmipBjbmQ9ZHF | Ccbbd6uUZF2GD5wE5LEfjGPA3YWPjoLC6P | 2021-06-10 23:13:59 | testVPS | 0 |
| 8 | CMKovgETx2oYxhoYKAeSakmipBjbmQ9ZHF | CYfMNQ62u1qwhCBqXzcmeJ8D9j4Yc1Pwef | 2021-06-10 20:03:59 | neco | 0 |
| 9 | CYfMNQ62u1qwhCBqXzcmeJ8D9j4Yc1Pwef | CMKovgETx2oYxhoYKAeSakmipBjbmQ9ZHF | 2021-06-10 21:03:59 | test | 0 |

My only input data which I sent from my mobile app is `receiveAddr` so I need to add this to group anything which containes address in either `sentAddr` or `receiveAddr`, here is representation of what I want to achieve

| user | otherParticipant | unread | lastMessage | text |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CMKovgETx2oYxhoYKAeSakmipBjbmQ9ZHF | Ccbbd6uUZF2GD5wE5LEfjGPA3YWPjoLC6P | 5 | 2021-06-10 23:13:59 | testVPS |
| CMKovgETx2oYxhoYKAeSakmipBjbmQ9ZHF | CYfMNQ62u1qwhCBqXzcmeJ8D9j4Yc1Pwef | 1 | 2021-06-10 21:03:59 | test |

It needs to have latest `text` counted amount of 0 in `read` column and `lastMessage` which is time of last message

I came up with something which sort of works if the user of the mobile app would be just receiving messages, which would be this:

> SELECT sentAddr, COUNT(IF(campus.messages.read = 0, 1, NULL)) as unread, max(receiveTime) as lastMessage, max(text) as text  FROM campus.messages WHERE (SELECT max(receiveTime) FROM campus.messages) AND receiveAddr = 'CMKovgETx2oYxhoYKAeSakmipBjbmQ9ZHF' GROUP BY sentAddr, receiveAddr

But sadly that does not get me a text from the latest message and not even taking into account that if the same user send some message, it shows as different group, which is not really helpful. I also came up with something which groups sendAddr and receiveAddr into one group no matter if it's on sending or receiving side:

> GROUP BY CONCAT(LEAST(receiveAddr,sentAddr),' ', GREATEST(receiveAddr, sentAddr))

However in that case I can't with this added to upper query, it does not retrieve latest text, which is useless. So is there any chance of doing this with one query, no matter how long and convoluted it would be? And just to remind, only input data is user's address, which can be either sending or receiving address from the table. So is there any solution to this?

Version of the mysql database is `8.0.25`

Comment: what does `select version();` show?

Comment: @ysth it's version ```8.0.25```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, here it is:

```
SELECT myMessages.user, 
       myMessages.otherParticipant, 
       groupList.unread, 
       groupList.lastMessage, 
       myMessages.text 
FROM (     SELECT IF(sentAddr = ?   , sentAddr, receiveAddr) AS user, 
                  IF(receiveAddr = ?, sentAddr, receiveAddr) AS otherParticipant, 
                  receiveTime, 
                  campus.messages.text, 
                  campus.messages.read 
           FROM campus.messages               ) myMessages 
INNER JOIN (SELECT otherParticipant, 
                   COUNT(IF(myMessages2.read = 0, 1, NULL))  AS unread, 
                   MAX(receiveTime)                          AS lastMessage 
            FROM (SELECT IF(receiveAddr = ?, sentAddr, receiveAddr) AS otherParticipant, 
                         receiveTime, 
                         campus.messages.read 
                  FROM campus.messages 
                  WHERE sentAddr = ? 
                     OR receiveAddr = ?       ) AS myMessages2 
            GROUP BY otherParticipant    ) groupList 
        ON myMessages.otherParticipant = groupList.otherParticipant 
       AND myMessages.receiveTime = groupList.lastMessage
```